# (Linux) Gnome-Screenshot & Cairo-dock

Tags: linux, gnome, screenshot, dock

I've been trying to add a gnome-screenshot launcher to cairo dock. I would like it to generate a random filename and save the screen after I've selected the screengrab area.

These are the 2 commands I have been trying:

```
    name=$RANDOM && gnome-screenshot -a --file=/home/user/Desktop/$name     
    gnome-screenshot -a --file=/home/user/Desktop/$RANDOM
```

Both work through a terminal, and also work from the cairo dock as long as I am not trying to randomize the filename.. I can only assume the error is with $RANDOM, OR Have I overlooked something in the dock itself?  I don't really know where to start here, the command appears to work fine unless it's used as a quick launch from the dock. God I hate asking questions like this, but here goes:
Does anybody know where I am making the mistake? I'd very much like to get around this..
  - Thanks in advance